# JPCT - 3D to 2D (flat perspective)

Tags: opengl, camera, perspective, flat, jpct

I'm using JPCT to create 3D modelling software. The center of the program has a big view of the model. There are xy, xz and yz views at the side to see each side of the model in detail.

The Problem I have is that I can not remove the "perspective" on the side views. I want a "flat top down" view. A point far in the distance should not be any closer to the center than a close point if they have the same xy position (in the xy view).
In other words: "Placing the camera in infinity and then zooming in" is what I want.

I tried fiddling around with the BillBoard Matrix, but no success (I don't even know if this is the right thing to look at). Unfortunately the documentation/examples for JPCT are sparse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear as of late 2010 [ortho is unsupported](http://www.jpct.net/forum2/index.php/topic,1789.msg13175.html?PHPSESSID=7694ef2dbda83d169e1fefdaacb076b8#msg13175):

> > 1. Is there a way to set an orthographic camera projection? There doesn't seem to be a way to specify the projection that the camera
> >        uses, other than setting the FOV. Perspective seems to be implied. How
> >        do I set it to ortho?
>
> Nope, orthographic mode isn't supported, i'm sorry.

Comment: I ended up placing the camera far away and narrowing down the FOV as recommended in the post you linked. This works well enough for me. Thank you!